# Highcharts API - loading and no data

Tags: highcharts

I would like to display "Loading" when my chart's data are fetching and if there's no data - I'd like to display "No Data". I tried with loading and noData properties from Highcharts API, but the effect is always the same - "Loading" overlaps with "No Data", and after some time "Loading" vanishes. Could anyone give me example where these two properties works fine when they are used simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared two demos shows how to achieve it.

- In the first, the chart is initialized with the series config (the data is an empty array) and I used the `setTimeout` as a simulation of fetching data. When data comes the series is updated depending if a new data is an empty array or not.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1dg2zyus/

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let data = [];
    //let data = [1,2,3,4,5];

  if (data.length) {
    chart.series[0].update({
      data: data
    })
  }

  chart.hideLoading();
}, 1000)
```

- In the second demo - the chart is initialized without the series config. Again, `setTimeout` is used as a simulation. When data comes - we can use the `addSeries` feature this time to add the data to the chart.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/97jd2v5e/

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let data = [];
    //let data = [1,2,3,4,5];

  if (data.length) {
    chart.addSeries({
      data: data
    })
  }

  chart.hideLoading();
}, 1000)
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: But it doesn't work properly - in the time of loading (1 second) we can still see both subtitles - 'No data' and 'Loading'. I would like to see only loading at the time of loading data and only 'No data' at the time of obtaining no data from API or DB.

Comment: @AndrzejSikorski Thank you for an explanation. You can achieve it by hiding/showing the label SVG element. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#show Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p4h7evb2/